# How to detect quirks mode in Safari 3.0.x?

Tags: javascript, safari, quirks-mode

Safari 3.0.x doesn't support the document.compatMode property to detect whether the document is rendered in standards or in quirks mode. Safari 3.1 and newer do support it. How do I detect the document mode in Safari 3.0.x if document.compatMode is not available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.ca/search?q=compatMode+safari) results in: ["HOWTO determine the document's compatibility mode"](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticleCompatMode)

Basically you create a `div` with an invalid css style that would only work in quirks mode. You then check the new `div`'s style to see if the css was accepted. If it was accepted, the document is in quirks mode.

To paraphrase [the code](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/source/browse/trunk/goog/dom/dom.js#1651):

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;width:0;height:0;width:1';
var compatMode = el.style.width === '1px' ? 'BackCompat' : 'CSS1Compat';
```

I would test this for you but I can't run Safari. Please test it if you can and report the results in a comment.

Comment: No good. That code results "BackCompat" in IE when IE is in standards mode.

Comment: The Google article uses Browser detection and expandos -- obviously no good.

Answer (score 2):

Most newer browsers have a `compatMode` but some older browsers don't. Such browsers include Mac IE and older WebKits, such as Safari 2 on desktop and many Nokia phones.

If `document.compatMode` exists, then check that the value is not `"BackCompat"`. If that is the case, the document is in Standards mode. This gets an early result for IE.

Otherwise, there's no `document.compatMode` and so it is an older browser that might support standards mode rendering, but just doesn't have a `compatMode` property.

If setting an element to have a number value for `width` sets its width, the document is not in standards mode.

You can use `if - else` if you find it more readable; or, alternatively, use a ternary assignment.

```
/* 2010-06-26 Garrett Smith - BSD License */
function isQuirksMode(doc) {
  doc = doc || document;
  var compatMode = doc.compatMode,
      testStyle,
      IS_STANDARDS_MODE = compatMode ? compatMode != "BackCompat" :
      doc.createElement && ((testStyle = doc.createElement("p").style).width = "1", 
       !testStyle.width);
  return !IS_STANDARDS_MODE;
}
```

This addresses older Webkit versions which may exist in mobile devices such as Nokias in countries around the world.

It will return true in IE5.5 and below. Existence inference check for `createElement` will fail on any browser that has createElement that is broken (Opera 5, I believe).

Avoid using this function to make general inferences; always try to be as specific as possible.